# Lightning Design System as a static resource not working

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to create a **Custom Scope CSS** for **Lightning Design System** using **Static Resources** and [CSS customizer](https://tools.lightningdesignsystem.com/css-customizer) but It's not working at all.

It updated the Sass files, zipped them out and tried to post them as Static Ressource but it fails because **the zip file is bigger than 5MO**.

I don't understand :

- Do I need to build the Sass files before zipping and uploading?
- Do I need to send all files or just modified ones?

Since I was not able to make it work with [CSS customizer](https://tools.lightningdesignsystem.com/css-customizer) and Sass files, I tried to edit the compiled css downloaded from [lightningdesignsystem.com documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/#zip) and post it as Static ressource 
Since Salesforce documentation is poor on the topic, I follow every step of [this tutorial](https://readsalesforce.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/upload-lightning-design-system-slds-as-a-static-resource-in-your-salesforce-org-lightning-experience-supported-org-salesforce-com/). Once again the zip is over 5MO. 
Actually, the zip downloaded by clicking *"Download Lightning Design System (Static Resource) (2.9.4)"* is over 5MO even before any changes (5.1MO).

What am I missing here?
Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention where you are trying to use SLDS. I assume its visualforce page since you are trying to upload in salesforce static resource.

If this is the case, you can use `apex:slds`.

Documentation:

> apex:slds Allows Visualforce pages to reference Lightning Design
>   System styling and to include custom themes. Use this component
>   instead of uploading the Lightning Design System as a static resource.
>
> Include  in a Visualforce page to use Lightning Design
>   System stylesheets in the page.

You can refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm

If its communities, lightning component will get styling slds be default as its lightning experience.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in Salesforce Communities

Comment: added answer...